# How do I indent after a line break command, in case the line before the line break is at least a certain length?

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, indentation, text

I want to an auto indentation after using the line break command, in case the line before the line break command has at least a certain lenght (in best case relative to my page width).

Example:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

to look lie this:

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
     bla bla bla bla bla.

and

```
bla bla bla bla bla \\
bla bla bla bla bla.
```

to look lie this:

bla bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla.

Sry for the bad formatting. First time I'm posting on this site.
Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

A demo showing the `\linegoal` from `linegoal` package (You need to compile twice to get the right output.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@wide@enough

\def\xnewline{%
  \@wide@enoughfalse
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\linegoal}%
  \ifdim\@tempdima<0.5\linewidth
    \@wide@enoughtrue
  \fi
  \\
  \if@wide@enough
    \hspace*{40pt}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

short line: abc abc abc \xnewline def def def

long line: abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc \xnewline def def def
\end{document}
```

[image]